# wordpress query_posts to look at meta info

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am looking to run a query with query_posts that lets me look at meta_fields.
I have done this once before and achieved the result I wanted but now for some reason adding an extra field into the equation returns nothing.

**The query below returns all `attachments` where the `lottery_year` is equal to `$y`, and obviously `$y` can be `2011` or earlier.**

Now my next step I want to bring in another `meta_field` called `photo_technique` and give that one a value.

Question, how do I do that?

```
$querystr = "
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.*
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
    WHERE ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'lottery_year' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = $y)
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'attachment'
    ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value ASC
    LIMIT 100
";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you whant to display posts that have either `lottery_year = $y` ( **or** ) `photo_technique = $x`, you could use :

```
$querystr = "
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.*
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
    WHERE ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'lottery_year' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = $y) OR ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'photo_technique' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = $x)
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'attachment'
    ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value ASC
    LIMIT 100
";
```

---

**Edit**

If you whant to display results that have both `lottery_year = $y` ( **AND** ) `photo_technique = $x`, you could use the following query :

```
$querystr = "
    SELECT
        $wpdb->posts.*
    FROM 
        $wpdb->posts
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON
        $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key IN ( 'lottery_year', 'photo_technique' )
        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value IN ( '$y', '$x' )
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'attachment'
    GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID
    HAVING COUNT(1) = 2
    ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value ASC
    LIMIT 100
";
```

---

**Edit**

The last query ( the AND one ) will fail in some circumstances. For example you whant 
`lottery_year = $y AND photo_technique = $x`, but it will allso return results that have the $x and $y switched like : `lottery_year = $x AND photo_technique = $y`, it realy depends when you can rely on it or not, like do you have a photo_technique that is called for example '2001' ( witch could pass as a lottery_year too ) . Please be carefull with it or ask this question on dba.stackexchange.com or wordpress.stackexchange.com .

Comment: and If I want to combine the two where it looks at both of those fields?

Comment: @ApPeL: give me a sec to try it out first

Comment: Yeah, I think the biggest issue I might run into is the face that the photo_technique should represent a "like %$x%", instead of an exact equal to.

Comment: you could try to use `AND ( $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = '$y' OR $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%$x%' )` ( but you might have problems with the indexes ... ) have't tested it but i will in a few moments and let you know if it works and if not i'll try to figure out another way of doing it